# How reactjs read response from SQL Server if i use nodejs to res it

Tags: sql-server, reactjs

I want to view my SQL Server data in reactjs, but I can't... the error was

> map is not function

I ask how I can convert SQL Server results into an array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include information about what you have tried already as well as the relevant code. Also, include a description on when you encounter the error